# Laravel Sanctum's createToken method tries to insert to wrong table

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to setup Laravel Sanctum to issue API tokens.

When I do `$user->createToken('test');`, it fails while attempting to insert the generated token into my `tokens` table which I had previously created to store third party API tokens.

I was expecting it to insert it into `personal_access_tokens` instead.

My guess is that somehow this `tokens` table and `Token` model interfere with Sanctum. In my `User` model, I have this method which return a user's third party API tokens:

```
public function tokens()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Token::class);
}
```

Any idea why it does that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The createToken method is like so :

```
    public function createToken(string $name, array $abilities = ['*'])
    {
        $token = $this->tokens()->create([
            'name' => $name,
            'token' => hash('sha256', $plainTextToken = Str::random(40)),
            'abilities' => $abilities,
        ]);

        return new NewAccessToken($token, $token->getKey().'|'.$plainTextToken);
    }
```

but I had already in my User model a `tokens` method. That why is was creating the token in the wrong table.